# Reg SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, document

Is there anyway to identify, in the SharePoint 2010 document library whether the document is uploaded from UI or explorer view? Is there any log to identify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use content ows_metaInfo property and try to find "vti_winfileattribs:" substring in it. It represents disk attributes of file and is presented only for files uploaded using Explorer view. There are also some other marks in ows_MetaInfo value but remember that this is not documented and thus supported way. But I have tested it and works fine for me.